# Android: How to update objects' variables in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have created an ArrayList which contains Currency objects (Currency has name and price).
And I have also created classes which extends baseAdapter and application classes.
So every time I add a Currency to the list, it goes through the application class by using this code:

```
getApplicationClass().addCurrency(currency);
```

However, prices of currencies keep updating.
So I'm wondering how can I update the currency prices? Is there any function that I can use from the library?

(ArrayList is inside application class)

Answer (score 0):

While it fine to keep the list of currencies in the Application class in order to display it that list will also have to be in a subclass of BaseAdapter.  When you add a currency to the list through the Application class you are bypassing the BaseAdapter subclass which is what the UI is listening to.  If you have the subclass of BaseAdapter hooked up to the UI while you are calling addCurrency() method on the Application class the UI won't see those changes.  Instead it would be a better idea to add through the BaseAdapter subclass so it can call notifyDataChanged() so the UI is aware of the change.  Also since it contains a reference to the same instance inside Application class (I'm assuming this is what you've done) the Application reference will also be updated.

If a price changes on a specific currency you just need to call notifyDataChanged() on the BaseAdapter subclass to tell the UI to redraw because something in the backing model has changed.

Without knowing more details of your program, that's all of the advice I can give and I'm also making some assumptions about what you are doing (ie the ArrayList inside Application class is the same instance given to the BaseAdapter subclass - not a copy).